# Electron Icon not building out with electron-packager

Tags: javascript, electron

When I build out my app it builds fine but the `.ico` file does not become the icon of the built out app. I am on mac and here is the commands I have tried:

```
electron-packager ./ --icon="./assets/icon.ico" --overwrite

electron-packager ./ --icon=./assets/icon.ico --overwrite

electron-packager ./ --icon="assets/icon.ico" --overwrite

electron-packager ./ --icon=assets/icon.ico --overwrite
```

From my root folder where my `package.json` file is there is a folder called `assets` and an ico file in there called `icon.ico` I cant seem to get the app built out with this icon as the app icon.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out it wanted `.icns` file not `.ico`. So the command is

`electron-packager . --icon="icon.icns"`

Where icon.icns is in my root where my `package.json` is

Comment: Thank you for this